# Adding image styles path in page.tpl

Tags: theming

i have image upload field in my theme-settings.php

```
$form['fsos_settings']['intro']['hero']['heroImage'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array(0 => 'png jpg jpeg gif'),
),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://image/home/',
    '#description' => t("Upload an image."),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('heroImage'),
);
```

I can print this in my page.tpl.php using the following code

```
<img src="<?php print file_create_url(file_load(theme_get_setting('heroImage'))->uri); ?>"/>
```

But i want to use Image Styles (heroimage) for the size. How can i get the image styles URL instead of the original URL

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141831/how-do-i-output-a-drupal-image-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example using theme_image_style()

```
$mypath = (file_load(theme_get_setting('heroImage'))->uri);
print theme_image_style(
  array(
    'style_name' => 'heroimage',
    'path' => $mypath,
    'attributes' => array(
    'class' => 'YOUR_IMAGE_CLASS'
    ),
    'width' => NULL,
    'height' => NULL,
   )
 );
}
```

I'll be honest, I cant remember why I set height and width to NULL, off the top of my head it helped fix some bug! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<img src="<?php print image_style_url('heroimage',$image_link_uri); ?>" />
```

**$image_link_uri** would be the URI link of your image

That should work !

Comment: could u give me example for the image style url

Comment: @user81244 See this doc https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7.x

Comment: @user81244 I just did it with that line, applying yout image style into that line, just replace the variable $image_link_uri with your uri file and you'll be done